# How do I search twitter API for users?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I've been trying to find the right url to receive a list of users based on a specific search (Ideally that would also contain the number of followers of each user that would appear in the search) but I can't seem to find it in twitter's documentation. I imagine it would be something along the lines of https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/users.json?q=Nike?api=[api key] (I already have an API key to use)

Answer (score 1):

The [Twitter Documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/search) lists a user search function as:

`https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json`

You will need to [sign the request with OAuth](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth).

Comment: I tried: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json?q=nike?oauth_token=[token], but I'm getting an error message:"{"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}". I'm pretty sure the token I'm using is good so am I signing it wrong?

Comment: The error message says your authentication is bad. That either means your token is wrong, or you've not signed it correctly. Which library are you using?